# What type of insurance are Florida Condominiums required to purchase?

Tags: florida, insurance, condominium

Assume that a Florida Condominium is governed by:  https://www.flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2002/Chapter718/All

> (a)  A unit-owner controlled association shall use its best efforts to
> obtain and maintain adequate insurance to protect the association, the
> association property, the common elements, and the condominium
> property required to be insured by the association pursuant to
> paragraph (b). If the association is developer controlled, the
> association shall exercise due diligence to obtain and maintain such
> insurance. Failure to obtain and maintain adequate insurance during
> any period of developer control shall constitute a breach of fiduciary
> responsibility by the developer-appointed members of the board of
> directors of the association, unless said members can show that
> despite such failure, they have exercised due diligence. An
> association **may also obtain** and maintain liability insurance for
> directors and officers, insurance for the benefit of association
> employees, and flood insurance for common elements, association
> property, and units. **An association or group of associations may**
> **self-insure against claims against the association**, the association
> property, and the condominium property required to be insured by an
> association, upon compliance with ss. 624.460-624.488. A copy of each
> policy of insurance in effect shall be made available for inspection
> by unit owners at reasonable times.

What exactly is the required?

- If flood insurance is not obtained is this unacceptable?
- If wind insurance (hurricane) is not obtained is this unacceptable?
- If fire insurance is not obtained is this unacceptable?
- If liability insurance is not obtained is this unacceptable?

Comment: Is the question about insurance types _purchased_ or risks _covered_? The text you highlighted says you don't have to purchase anything as long as you properly meet self-insurance regulations.

Comment: Usually, the governing documents of an HOA will provide more specific guidance than the relevant statutes.

Comment: @user71659 Thanks for the reply: assume that HOA does not have the funds to self insure / cover.  Therefore any coverage is in the form of purchased insurance.